# JQuery lavalamp: Selecting focus/highlighting item within lavalamp when hyperlinks outside lavalamp bar are pressed

Tags: jquery, focus, lavalamp

Hi I'm hoping someone can help me out with a jQuery lavalamp problem.

I have the following
- a menu bar using lavalamp.
- a div where content is loaded into when link on menu bar is clicked
- in my content div I have some links that link to the same pages as in the menu bar

The menu bar itself, looks and works great. However I wan't to be able to focus on / highlight the corresponding menu item "Menu Option" when a user clicks on one of the links within my content div.

EG

```
<div><ul class="lavalamp">
  <li><a href="Item 1.html">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="Item 2.html">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="Item 3.html">item 3</a></li>
 </div>

<div id="dynamic-content">
   <a href="Item3.html">Item 3.html</a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on item 3  within the dynamic content div the selection on the lavalamp should change.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which jQuery lavaLamp you are using. If you are using [this one](http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/), use SimpleCoder's answer. If you are using [this one](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/), try this:

```
    $(function() {
        var loc = window.location.href;
        var filename = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/')+1, loc.length);

         $('.lavalamp a, #dynamic-content a').each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('href') == filename){
               $(this).parent().addClass('current');
            }
         });

        $(".lavalamp").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700
         })
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the selection on the lavalamp, redefine the lavalamp using the `lavaLamp()` function passing a `startItem` parameter:

```
$('#myLavalamp').lavaLamp({startItem: 4});
```

Note that numbering starts at 0 for elements. Also, you will have to include all of your other options that you used to initialize the lavalamp originally.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(function() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    var filename = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/')+1, loc.length);

     $('#2 a, #dynamic-content a').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(filename)>-1){
           $(this).parent().addClass('current');
        }
     });

    $("#2").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout",
        speed: 700
     })
});
```